# Python Pandas. Describe() by date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to plot summary statistics over time for panel data. The X axis would be time and the Y axis would be the variable of interest with lines for Mean, min/max, P25, P50, P75 etc.

This would basically loop through and calc the stats for each date over all the individual observations and then plot them.

What I am trying to do is similar to below, but y axis would be dates instead of 1-10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Create random data
rd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10))
rd.describe().T.drop('count', axis=1).plot()
```

In my dataset, the time series of each individual is stacked on one another.

I tried running the following but I seem to get the descriptive stats of entire dataset and not broken down by date.

```
rd = rd.groupby('period').count().describe()
print (rd)
rd.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dataframe below as the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[10,20,30,20,40,60,40,80,120],'period': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
df

    Values  period
0   10      1
1   20      2
2   30      3
3   20      1
4   40      2
5   60      3
6   40      1
7   80      2
8   120     3
```

Now,plotting the descriptive statistics by date using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('period').describe()['Values'].drop('count', axis = 1).plot()
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting your code runs, however when I replace with my dataframe I get the following error: AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'describe'

Comment: Can you show your dataframe please? You could edit the main question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the dataframe.Maybe I'll understand why it is getting the  error.

Comment: added the code in edit. I think I need to add my data to the dataframe first in some way? Thanks.

Comment: What I am asking is if you could share how your dataframe looks like. Is it like the `df` in the example I provided?

Comment: Added the df. I think it needs to be added to a pandas df?

Comment: in a pandas dataframe, it works fine. I did not realize you still did not have it as a dataframe. In which format do you have it on?

Comment: It was created from pyspark I think. Sorry I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Ahh ok ok. I'm not used to work with spark dataframes. You can turn your pyspark data frame to a pandas dataframe by doing the following: `df_pandas = df.toPandas()`, as explained [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/convert-pyspark-dataframe-to-pandas/#:~:text=Convert%20PySpark%20Dataframe%20to%20Pandas%20DataFrame,small%20subset%20of%20the%20data.)

After turning it into a pandas dataframe, it should work